# Choosing between two ATX and Micro ATX motherboards (GA-P55M-UD2 and GA-P55-US3L)

Tags: motherboard, atx

I need help in deciding whether to buy a [GA-P55-US3L](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=MB-207-GI) or [GA-P55M-UD2](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=MB-209-GI&groupid=701&catid=5&subcat=1495) ([Comparison](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_ComparisonSheet.aspx?ProductID=3167,3165)). They cost about the same and have the same features (or at least the ones I am interested in) but the UD2 is mATX.

Are there any problems associated with mATX rather than ATX in terms of space or expansion ports or anything else? I notice that the UD2 has 3 fewer PCI Slots and is also smaller. Will a modern graphics card like an ATI 5770 still fit in there?

Note I am using an ATX/mATX case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an ATX/mATX case, using an mATX motherboard will just provide you with even more room inside the case (yay!). A regular card should fit fine as long as your case can fit them, and your other hardware components aren't too big either.

You can find the measurements of most hardware online before you buy it.

Answer (score 1):

> Will a modern graphics card like an
>   ATI 5770 still fit in there?

in a word, yes.

unless you're using a slim case that requires low-profile cards, that is.